# Sharing data under 2 controllers through common Service in angular .js

Tags: javascript, angularjs

```
(function () {
'use strict';

angular.module('ShoppingListCheckOff', [])
.controller('ToBuyController', ToBuyController)
.controller('AlreadyBoughtController', AlreadyBoughtController)
.service("ShoppingListCheckOffService", ShoppingListCheckOffService);

ToBuyController.$inject = ["ShoppingListCheckOffService"];

function ToBuyController(ShoppingListCheckOffService) {

  var buyItem = this;

  buyItem.items = ShoppingListCheckOffService.getItems();
  buyItem.removeItem = function (itemIndex) {
  ShoppingListCheckOffService.removeItem(itemIndex);
  }
}

AlreadyBoughtController.$inject = ["ShoppingListCheckOffService"];
function AlreadyBoughtController(ShoppingListCheckOffService){
    var boughtItem = this;

    boughtItem.itemName = "";
    boughtItem.itemQuantity = "";
    // console.log(boughtItem.name);


    boughtItem.items = function () {
      ShoppingListCheckOffService.addItem(boughtItem.itemName, boughtItem.itemQuantity);
    }

  //  boughtItem.items = ShoppingListCheckOffService.getItems();

  }


function ShoppingListCheckOffService() {
  var service = this;

  // List of shopping items
  var items = [{
    name: "Donuts",
    quantity: "200"
  },
  {
    name: "Cookies",
    quantity: "10"
  },
  {
    name: "Cake",
    quantity: "1"
  },
  {
    name: "Bread",
    quantity: "2"
  },
  {
    name: "Candies",
    quantity: "30"
  }
];

  service.addItem = function (itemName, itemQuantity) {
    var newItems = [];
    var item = {
      name: itemName,
      quantity: itemQuantity
    };
    newItems.push(item);
    return newItems;
  };

  service.removeItem = function (itemIndex) {
    items.splice(itemIndex, 1);

  };

  service.getItems = function () {
    return items;
  };
}

})();
```

HTML Code:

```
<!-- To Buy List -->
    <div class="col-md-6" ng-controller='ToBuyController as buyItem'>
     <h2>To Buy:</h2>
     <ul>
       <li ng-repeat="item in buyItem.items">
         Buy {{item.quantity }} of {{ item.name }}
         <button ng-click="buyItem.removeItem($index)" class="btn btn-default"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok">Bought</button>
       </li>
     </ul>
     <div class="emptyMessage">Everything is bought!</div>

    </div>

    <!-- Already Bought List -->
    <div class="col-md-6" ng-controller='AlreadyBoughtController as boughtItem'>
     <h2>Already Bought:</h2>
     <ul>
       <li ng-repeat="item in boughtItem.items">
         Bought {{ item.quantity }} of {{ item.name }}
       </li>
     </ul>
     <div class="emptyMessage">Nothing bought yet.</div>
    </div>
```

How can code it so that clicking on "Bought" removes from one list and shows on another Div. Two different controllers used under same Service. Under the controller "AlreadyBoughtController" addItem() is not working properly

Answer (score 0):

You are creating blank array in `addItem` method and adding item in that. So you need to change you `addItem` method like as-

```
service.addItem = function (itemName, itemQuantity) {    
    var item = {
      name: itemName,
      quantity: itemQuantity
    };
    items.push(item);
    return items ;
  };
```

Comment: Doing this also, the items are not added under the other div "Already Bought " in View. Only the items are removed from "To Buy"